# which is best amoung Cloud Firestone and Realtime Database in FIrebase for working with large and complex data structure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing android and IOS app with web backend admin support for an organisation oriented employee, tasks and issue management system. issues and the task will be posted by any public people and issue will be addressed and solved by the organization people.

my app will have **dynamic keyword filtering over the new issue posting** and an *algorithm will keep running* to *identify the issue categories dynamically* from the issues being posted.

my app or the **search result and filters should be fast** in retrieving the data and **it should not affect my application performance**. I didn't know which one is good to use for a case like this.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Realtime database for an large iOS app that contains users, jobs for users, favourites, messages etc. So I need the database to show results in realtime as well as being reliable.

The best features for a big app like the one I have built are the

**offline capabilities**
If the user goes offline, the database is still responsive and persists data to the disk which resynchronises when connection is established.

**Data synchronization**
All of my users on the app can see changes happening instantly such as notifications and messages, job updates etc. It's reliable and stops any overlapping potential risk.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Additionally, it sounds like you will benefit from the easy JSON structure that Firebase Realtime database offers to build categories etc.

I use a lot of filters in my iOS app and the calls to the database return results almost instantly given a connection is established; its very flexible.

In terms of reliability
Cloud Firestore is currently in beta. Stability in a beta product is not always the same as that of a fully launched product, where as Realtime Database is a mature product.

Answer (score -2):

Use Fire-Base Realtime database if your apps are not going to serve more than 1000 people.

Because Fire-base Realtime doesn't perform much complex and fast queries like Fire-Base FireStore. And you can not upgrade your app if your app is based on RealTime database.

FireStore has more features that Realtime database.

You can go and check the difference between both of them:- 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore